# badge-request tag should not require feature-request on meta

Tags: discussion

Why do I have to tag a question both as tag-request and feature-request?

Answer (score 3):

Because feature-request is a required tag for Meta. And technically requesting a new badge is a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need no stinking badge-requests!

Comment: For the most part, we don't. I would say over 90% of the badge requests aren't serious and will never be implemented.